# Check if item is shortcut before actioning in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a written a script that essentially grabs the contents of folder1 (child items) and moves it to another share location all based off a spreadsheet document.

I then have it write a shortcut in the original location to the new share location - this is all just until we can get more storage space!

The problem I'm facing is if either:

1. Someone has created a shortcut previously (manually)
2. I re-run the script

It moves the shortcuts to the new location, and then creates shortcuts for the actual files and directories, but also the original shortcuts!

Example:

```
Directory 1                  Directory 2
- folder1                    - folder 1
-- sub 1
-- sub 2

## script runs ##

Directory 1                  Directory 2
- folder1                    - folder 1
-- sub 1.lnk                 -- sub 1
-- sub 2.lnk                 -- sub 2

## script is ran again ##

Directory 1                  Directory 2
- folder1                    - folder 1
-- sub 1.lnk                 -- sub 1
-- sub 2.lnk                 -- sub 2
-- sub 1.lnk.lnk             -- sub 1.lnk
-- sub 2.lnk.lnk             -- sub 2.lnk
```

The issue I'm facing is that the original `.lnk` shortcut doesn't have the extension on the file originally, but it adds it after the re-generation.

I have tried:

```
$fileExtension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
if($fileExtension -eq '.lnk') {
  # skip
} else {
  # Move-Item ...
}
```

But this doesn't work.

This is the portion of code that I'm working with:

```
$original = $csv.column1     # \\nas1\share\1\...
$destination = $csv.column2  # \\nas2\share\1\...

# // MARK: get the sub items
if( Test-Path "$original" ) {
  $originalChildItems = Get-ChildItem "$original"
}

# loop the sub items
ForEach( $originalChildItem in $originalChildItems ) {

  # check if child exists in destination
  if( Test-Path( "$destination" + "\" + "$originalChildItem" ) ) {
    # already exists - error check here
  } else {
    
    # if file extension is .lnk
    $fileExtension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($originalChildItem)

    if( $fileExtension -eq ".lnk" ) {
      # Don't move item
    } else {
      # Move-Item ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$file`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `$file` is a file or directory from `Get-ChildItem` and looped out

Comment: In that case you can inspect `$file.Extension` directly. That being said, your existing code should work as well. Can you perhaps show us the whole script? Or at least the full loop over `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added in original. `$file` and `$originalChildItem` are the same, just trying to transfer from RDP copy/paste wasn't working